# Does express.js compression middleware not work using angular universal deployed to azure web app?

Tags: angular, express, azure-web-app-service, gzip, angular-universal

So I have deployed a SSR Angular application to azure in a Linux web app and I cannot find any information on why the express.js compression middleware ([docs](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/compression.html)) shouldn't work.

When I run the application locally everything works fine, but when deployed to azure the gzip encoding just doesnt work.

If anyone wanna have a look the url is https://kulturstoten.azurewebsites.net/

[image: running on http://localhost:4200]

[image: running in azure]

express.js code

```
import 'zone.js/node';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';

import { AppServerModule } from 'server';
import { REQUEST, RESPONSE } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';
import { DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { cacheControl } from './middleware/cache-control';
import { ControllerFactory } from './controllers/controller-factory';
import { ContentController } from './controllers/content-controller';
import { logError } from './middleware/log-error';
import * as compression from 'compression';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const factory = new ControllerFactory(server, '*/api/v1');
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/kulturstoten-frontend/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.html'))
    ? 'index.html'
    : 'index';

  server.use(compression());
  server.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/json' }));
  server.use(cacheControl);

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/main/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine(
    'html',
    ngExpressEngine({
      bootstrap: AppServerModule,
    })
  );

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get(
    '*.*',
    express.static(distFolder, {
      maxAge: '1y',
    })
  );

  factory.create(ContentController);

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, {
      req,
      providers: [
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl },
        { provide: REQUEST, useValue: req },
        { provide: RESPONSE, useValue: res },
        {
          provide: LOCALE_ID,
          useValue: 'se-SE',
        },
        {
          provide: DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE,
          useValue: 'SEK',
        },
      ],
    });
  });

  server.use(logError);
  server.disable('x-powered-by');
  return server;
}
```

Angular.json configuration settings

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "kulturstoten-frontend": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/kulturstoten-frontend/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "optimization": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": {
                  "minify": true,
                  "inlineCritical": false
                },
                "fonts": true
              },
              "sourceMap": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.production.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.development.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "kulturstoten-frontend:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "kulturstoten-frontend:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "kulturstoten-frontend:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": ["zone.js", "zone.js/testing"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/kulturstoten-frontend/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.production.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.development.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "kulturstoten-frontend:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "kulturstoten-frontend:server:development"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "kulturstoten-frontend:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "kulturstoten-frontend:server:production"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
          "options": {
            "routes": ["/"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "kulturstoten-frontend:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "kulturstoten-frontend:server:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "kulturstoten-frontend:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "kulturstoten-frontend:server:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried disabling the outputhashing in Angular.json for the production build, but then it didn't run at all in azure. I had a theory that the naming scheme of for example "main..js" somehow messed with the compression middleware so that it wouldn't know that it was a file that should be compressed.

I also tried upgrading from the free tier on azure, just to test if encoding headers was somehow behind a paywall.